# Data profiling in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-profiling

I want to profile every single data table I have in my Power BI report. By data profile I mean something like this:

[image: Example on a data profile]

Are there ways to make a data profile view in Power BI? DAX measure or calculated columns?

Alternatively, you can also recommend other data quality tools that can handle such tasks since I find it a bit difficult to achieve this result in Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

Now I feel dumb after writing a manual query that did what it turns out Table.Profile does in one shot. However I will mention you can automatically get a profile for every table in your data set by using the #shared reference and filtering down to the tables:

```
let
    Source = #shared,
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "TableCheck", each Type.Is(Value.Type([Value]), type table)),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([TableCheck] = true)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Name] <> "NAME_OF_THIS_QUERY"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Profile", each Table.Profile([Value])),
    #"Expanded Profile" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Profile", {"Column", "Min", "Max", "Average", "StandardDeviation", "Count", "NullCount", "DistinctCount"}, {"Profile.Column", "Profile.Min", "Profile.Max", "Profile.Average", "Profile.StandardDeviation", "Profile.Count", "Profile.NullCount", "Profile.DistinctCount"})
in
    #"Expanded Profile"
```

And replace "NAME_OF_THIS_QUERY" with whatever you name the query so it doesn't try to profile itself.

Comment: thanks for that. it is still valuable to have the MDX:)

Comment: Very valuable ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In the query editor, you can use the [Table.Profile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/table-profile) on any table.

You can do multiple ones simultaneously like this:

```
= Table.Combine({Table.Profile(Table1),Table.Profile(Table2)})
```

---

**Edit:**

To see the profile, create a new Blank Query and define it as `= Table.Profile(Table1)`. If you open the Advanced Editor, the M code looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.Profile(Table1)
in
    Source
```

Comment: can you please send a screenshot on where in the query editor? I have some trouble to find out where do perform this function

Comment: You can write custom code in the Advanced Editor under the Home tab in the Power Query Editor.

Comment: @RezaAzimi, I have same question: Where does one enter `Table.Profile(TableName)`? You can't just slap it in the Advanced Editor as it will interfere with existing code there.

Answer (score 0):

**Power BI has a built-in data profiler**

1. Open Power BI and refer to the menu ribbon
2. Click Home
3. Click Edit Queries
4. Click View
5. Select Column Profile to view stats about your data

---

[image: Power BI Ribbon]